# If $\cos(A)-4\sin(A)=1$ then what are the possible values of $\sin(A)+4\cos(A)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Given that

$$\cos(A)-4\sin(A)=1.$$

What are the possible values of $\sin(A)+4\cos(A)$?

This is rather a very difficult and unfamiliar question, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: No of  sin(A)+4cos(A)

Answer (score 3):

$$(\cos A-4\sin A)^2+(4\cos A+\sin A)^2=?$$

This is a corollary of [Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity)

Comment: How do you know if you have introduced an extraneous solution?

Comment: @DanielV, That is why "the possible values"

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle \cos A - 4\sin A = \sqrt{17}\cos(A + \arctan 4)$

$\displaystyle \sin A + 4\cos A = \sqrt{17}\sin (A + \arctan 4)$

Hence the latter is equal to $\displaystyle \pm\sqrt{17}\sqrt{1 - (\frac{1}{\sqrt{17}})^2} = \pm 4$

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos(A)−4\sin(A)=1 \iff \cos(A)=1+4\sin(A)$$
Substitute this $\cos(A)$ in $\sin(A)+4\cos(A)$:

$$\begin{align*}\sin(A)+4\cos(A)&=\sin(A)+4(1+4\sin(A))\\
              &=\sin(A)+4+16\sin(A)\\
              &=4+17\sin(A)\end{align*}$$

The range of $\sin(A)$ is $[-1,1]$, so the range of $\sin(A)+4\cos(A)$ will be $[-13,21]$.

Comment: This answer does not take into account that there is a trigonometric relationship between the values of $\sin A$ and $\cos A$.

Comment: Please use $\LaTeX$ to typeset math. There are many resources online. Here is one: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: The answer is wrong. The correct one is 4, -4.